# MSSQL: Update value from another row and another column from the same table based on conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, reference, dimension

I need to update value in fact table from another row and column on the same table based on conditions and reference from another dimension table.

[image]
 contains sample of sales rows (two items, two days, two sites).

[image]
 contains only one row in this example.

What I try to find is one SQL query which updates qty to qty_ref where site and date matches - and when there is a match from reference table. I hope my pictures helps explaining this.

I'm using Azure SQL database with SQL Server 2016.

My fact table contains millions of rows and dim_ref table can grow up to couple of thousands of rows.

Comment: It might help us understand if you edit your question to include the SQL you already wrote to do this which isn't quite working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple update with an inner join should do the trick:

```
UPDATE f1 
SET qty_ref = f2.qty 
FROM fact_sales f1 
INNER JOIN dim_item_ref d ON(f1.item = d.item)
INNER JOIN fact_sales f2 ON(d.item_ref = f2.item)
WHERE f1.site = f2.site
AND f1.date = f2.date
```

Comment: Thank you! I was too afraid joining huge fact table to itself. I thought the best solution would use window functions etc, but it seems inner joining large tables is not that resource intensive at all.